# Cell getCoordinate returns the value for the last cell created, not the cell object in the variable

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am making a class which can be loaded up with style information and then passed an array of cells to apply the styles to. A problem I have encountered is that when you get a cell object via `$phpExcel->getCell('A1');` and then get another, the original value loses information (sort of).

The PHPExcel `getCoordinate`, `getRow`, and `getColumn` functions get their information from the currently active cell, the cell reference, row, or column indexes do not seem to be stored on the actual cell object. This presents a problem that can be seen with the code below. I grab and store the cell objects for three cells, A1, B2, and C3. I print the information for these cells as I grab them and then do a final dump at the end. The coordinates, rows, or columns of a cell return those of the last cell created. The final lines of the code set the value on the cells. These values are set correctly on each cell when the document is exported.

```php
print "Var\tRef\tCol\tRow\n";

$a1 = $sheet->getCell('A1')->setValue('a1');
print "A1\t" . $a1->getCoordinate() . "\t" . $a1->getColumn() . "\t" . $a1->getRow() . "\n";

$b2 = $sheet->getCell('B2')->setValue('b2');
print "B2\t" . $b2->getCoordinate() . "\t" . $b2->getColumn() . "\t" . $b2->getRow() . "\n";

$c3 = $sheet->getCell('C3')->setValue('c3');
print "C3\t" . $c3->getCoordinate() . "\t" . $c3->getColumn() . "\t" . $c3->getRow() . "\n";

print "----------------------------\n";

print "A1\t" . $a1->getCoordinate() . "\t" . $a1->getColumn() . "\t" . $a1->getRow() . "\n";
print "B2\t" . $b2->getCoordinate() . "\t" . $b2->getColumn() . "\t" . $b2->getRow() . "\n";
print "C3\t" . $c3->getCoordinate() . "\t" . $c3->getColumn() . "\t" . $c3->getRow() . "\n";

$a1->setValue('test');
$b2->setValue('test');
$c3->setValue('test');
```

The print output for the above code is:

```
Var Ref Col Row
A1  A1  A   1
B2  B2  B   2
C3  C3  C   3
----------------------------
A1  C3  C   3
B2  C3  C   3
C3  C3  C   3
```

The CSV output for the above code is:

```
"test","",""
"","test",""
"","","test"
```

How can I get the cell reference for a particular cell object without storing the cell in an associative array when it is first returned from the `getCell` function?

Comment: Don't, I repeat don't, store cell objects as variables; because PHPExcel will only ever reference the last accessed cell, so any subsequent reference to another cell will change the value of that stored cell

Comment: That is unfortunate. Some functions like getStyle() take a cell reference as a parameter. Perhaps I will just need a list of cell references instead of cell objects and use those in my styler class. Thanks for the response.

Comment: That's all you need for getStyle(), a cell reference; and if you can use a cell range (e.g. `'A1:A10'`) for getStyle() then it's a lot more efficient than setting style for every individual cell